# annotate django query by substring

Tags: django, django-queryset

How do you annotate a query set using a substring from a field?

I presume something like this:

```
query_by_domain = (
    queryset
    .annotate(domain=Substr("email", F("email").Index("@") + 1))
    .values("domain")
    .annotate(count=Count("id"))
    .order_by("domain")
)
```

Comment: So what is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`StrIndex`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#strindex) and work with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Value as V
from django.db.models.functions import StrIndex, Substr

queryset.values(domain=Substr('email', StrIndex('email', V('@')) + 1)).annotate(
    count=Count('id')
).order_by('domain')
```

Comment: V imported from?

Comment: @Ajax: sorry, that was a typo, `V` instead of `F`.

Comment: Sure you can import V from django.db.models?